# Refine my T-SQL query to increase performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

Created a SQL query to summarize some data. It is slow, so I thought I'd ask for some help.

Table is a log table that has :

```
loc, tag, entrytime, exittime, visits, entrywt, exitwt
```

My test log has 700,000 records in it. The `entrytime` and `exittime` are epoch values.

I know my query is inefficient as it rips through the table 4 times.

```
select 
    loc, edate, tag,
    (select COUNT(*) from mylog as ml 
     where mvlog.loc = ml.loc 
       and mvlog.edate = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(ss, ml.entrytime, '19700101')) 
       and mvlog.tag = ml.tag) as visits,
    (select SUM(entrywt - exitwt) from mylog as ml2 
     where mvlog.loc = ml2.loc 
       and mvlog.edate = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(ss, ml2.entrytime, '19700101')) 
       and mvlog.tag = ml2.tag) as consumed,
    (select SUM(exittime - entrytime) from mylog as ml3 
     where mvlog.loc = ml3.loc 
       and mvlog.edate = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(ss, ml3.entrytime, '19700101')) 
       and mvlog.tag = ml3.tag) as occupancy
from 
    eventlogV as mvlog with (INDEX(pt_index))
```

Index `pt_index` is made up of columns `tag` and `loc`.

When I run this query, it completes in roughly 30 seconds. Since my query is inefficient, I am sure it can be better.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?  Maybe give us some table/index definitions?

Comment: `eventlogV` and `mylog` are two different tables?

Comment: I believe that any kind of `refine` question is better posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Sorry.  eventlogV is a view on the mylog table.  Utlimately I have multiple records like loc tag entrytime.   entrytime is epoch so its seconds since 01/01/1970.  When query runs I want 1 record for each loc tag date that summaries fields from all the equivalent loc tag entrytime records.  I haven't generated an execution plan so I'll dig it up and provide it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can just LEFT JOIN mylog  to eventlogV  once and get the same results.

```
SELECT  mvlog.loc,
        mvlog.edate,
        mvlog.tag,
        COUNT(ml.loc) AS visits,
        SUM(entrywt - exitwt) AS consumed,
        SUM(exittime - entrytime) AS occupancy
FROM    eventlogV AS mvlog
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mylog ml ON mvlog.loc = ml.loc
                                    AND mvlog.edate = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(ss,ml.entrytime,'19700101'))
                                    AND mvlog.tag = ml.tag
GROUP BY mvlog.loc,
        mvlog.edate,
        mvlog.tag
```

Comment: Ran your version of the query and it completed in 25 seconds vs 30 seconds for the original.

Comment: That's not hard to believe..  the `AND mvlog.edate = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(ss,ml.entrytime,'19700101'))` part is probably your killer

Comment: can you add a computed column to `mylog` table and convert the  `entrytime` value to a date value?